when using hibernate getting error Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.example.JpaRevision.repository.courseRepository'
when using jpa specification along with hibernate below error is occuring i have created one to one relation between course and courseMaterial and started the application but it's not working due to below error
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.example.JpaRevision.repository.courseRepository'

below is the code from courseRepository
package com.example.JpaRevision.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.JpaRevision.entity.course;

@Repository
public interface courseRepository extends JpaRepository<course,Long>{

}

below is the code from courseMaterialRepository
package com.example.JpaRevision.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.JpaRevision.entity.courseMaterial;

@Repository
public interface courseMaterialRepository extends JpaRepository<courseMaterial,Long>{

    
}

below is the entity class created for courseMaterial
package com.example.JpaRevision.entity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.example.JpaRevision.repository.courseMaterialRepository;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class courseMaterial {
    
    @Autowired
    private courseMaterialRepository coureMat;
    
            @Id
            @SequenceGenerator(
            name="courseMaterial_Sequence",
            sequenceName="courseMaterial_Sequence"
            )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator="courseMaterial_Sequence"
            )
    private Long courseMaterialId;
    private String courseMaterialName;
    private String courseMaterialPrice;
    
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(
            name="course_id",
            referencedColumnName="courseId"
            )
    private course courseData;

}

below is the entity class for course
package com.example.JpaRevision.entity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.example.JpaRevision.repository.courseRepository;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class course {
    
    @Autowired
    private courseRepository coureRepo;
    
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="course_sequence",
            sequenceName="course_sequence",
            allocationSize=1
            )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator="course_sequence")
    private Long courseId;
    private String courseName;
    private double costPrice;
    //private courseMaterial courseMat;
}

below is the pom.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JpaRevision</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JpaRevision</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



Remove courseRepository from your entity. @Autowired won't work here anyway. For your future endavours, learn how to use Java standards, like uppercase first letters for classname, lower names in package names etc. For posting on stackoverflow take care of whatyou are posting as you now have mixed text and code in one large cod eblock, which is totally unreadable.
